# Google analytics not updating properly

Tags: android, analytics

First i would like to mention that when I first generated my property id, I had troubles integrating analytics so I didn't get to start using it until about a week later or so. Within this time I aleady had activity showing up in my analytics account. for smoe reason it was all apple devices. And none of the sources are places where i ever visited. So I finally managed to get everything set up two days ago. I know it's suppose to take time for it to show up, but since I did have quite a hard time trying to set it up, i'm thinking that I may have messed something up. anyways, here's the gist of my AnalyticsTracker1 Class

https://gist.github.com/asonofman/b7dcf407cd0d109e51a4

And heres a gist of my global_tracker.xml https://gist.github.com/asonofman/62ed1b70a64b90b71ca8

Answer (score 0):

this can be made simple by adding

in oncreate method

```
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
           t = analytics.getTracker(Reference.TRACKERID); 



protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        t.sendView("Feedslist");

    };
```

for this include googleAnalyticsV2.jar in your libs folder

Comment: I was told with the new update you don't need to add any jar file and that you only have to download the neccesary files through the sdk manager. And where exactly am I suppose to add this to? I'm guessing you only posted a snippet of something with a bigger scope.

Comment: @ThatThatson yes this code part is working in my project.Please try the same.